# Make Django-leaflet popup always open to display django-geojson feature properties

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make popup open on page load on django-leaflet. How can I do this?

```
var collection = {{ object_list|geojsonfeature:"popupContent"|safe }};
      console.log(collection);
    
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
          layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent).openPopup();
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
 function onEachFeature(feature, layer) { 

    // does this feature have a property named popupContent?
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {

        layer.addTo(map).bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent,{autoClose:false}).openPopup();
};  

}
```